# MismatchSenderId from Google FCM

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have connected my Android apps to Firebase and see in application root folder file google-service.json
I have created background service MessagingService and add in to AndroidManifest.xml
Service has ordinary template:

```
class MessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService()
{
     private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    override fun onNewToken(token: String)
    {
        super.onNewToken(token)
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(token) && Preferences.hasUserContext(this@MessagingService))
        {
            val user = Preferences.getUserContext(this@MessagingService)
            if (user != null)
            {
                // send token to server
                subscribeForPush(this@MessagingService, user.id!!, token)
            }
        }
    }
    companion object
    {
        @JvmStatic
        fun retrieveTokenAndSubscribeForPush(context: Context)
        {
            FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<InstanceIdResult?> ->
                if (!task.isSuccessful || task.result == null)
                {
                    return@addOnCompleteListener
                }
                val token = task.result!!.token
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(token) && Preferences.hasUserContext(context))
                {
                    val user = Preferences.getUserContext(context)
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        // send token to server
                        subscribeForPush(context, user.id!!, token)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
...
```

After subsrbe I have token like this
el2mMmTIRgOVxIN5gCNfuK:APA91bHXmj43evM2Xz76MoFDULGVmGCHyS6lIogIOa8Ph9ZqGwuRU3nYZNY4YDQkGI5Nc-SBaOVkNdHIWaxc4ABCF-T6_3Oe04VL9LUYmkXBLTBUQidOxsV-4KWLgdGHSUSDE9yU9REF

Also I see my ServerKey in Firease console like
AAAAiMkLYeI:APA91bG7-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxzQfpApUwEzg9vGeH9uPJkFQUNowjlLiT1BVyd_aTnQU_PYA4jY1c5gAOe-f-e6iW9l7BQmSs3ZSH7mOrKLk_kppDao88O7I4OIMp

I try to receive POST message from composer to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
with header

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key=AAAAiMkLYeI:APA91bG7-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxzQfpApUwEzg9vGeH9uPJkFQUNowjlLiT1BVyd_aTnQU_PYA4jY1c5gAOe-f-e6iW9l7BQmSs3ZSH7mOrKLk_kppDao88O7I4OIMp
Host: fcm.googleapis.com
Content-Length: 255
```

and Body

```
{
  "data":{
          "Trip_ID":"91505106-3F33-4508-A778-F7161949687E"
   },
  "to":"fvXclPSrROiOquWjdueMCx:APA91bFfD2y-s4vQVFCuJFiYQUc0Lym_6zR4krFumx3GLIzzuT4ST6eyWwQmJmSqZCpSr5QTNhQQPPQ99bgYp5IgiDIbP0OtrX2d8XIpjdE92rmo5NUpHfr4YEDHS6fvzNRg6Y9tm7uh"
}
```

But receive - "results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]

What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue, need to set correct data inside "TO" field. For example if subscribe look as

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subsribeToTopic("weather")
```

correct calling FCM look as

[image]